# Get camera frame from Vuforia in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, vuforia

I want to create a simple AR application using unity3d, vuforia package and opencv. Normally in unity AR app, selected 2d target is found and virtual 3d object is projected.

I want to change these scenario.

1. Open AR camera
2. Get frame from camera
3. Process the frame using opencv functions(maybe opencvsharp)
4. Find marker and project virtual object

To do this task, I did below steps :

1. create a new project in `unity`
2. import `vuforia package`
3. delete `main camera`
4. add AR camera

The AR camera has 3 `c#` files, I open and look them. But I don't see any code open camera and get frame. The screenshot is below :

[image]

**EDIT**

Accepted answer helps load user defined marker.

Comment: The Vuforia SDK is a bit closed. Much of the scripts are nothing more than wrappers to the SDK DLLs. Not a specialist of Vuforia, but you may encounter trouble to get any intermediate values.

Comment: @Kamalen this work is really hard for beginners like me. But there is an example that controls unity game screen(not AR screen)  from an opencv window. Maybe this example helps anyone. [link](https://github.com/hasanavi/OpenCV-Unity3D-Object-Tracking)

Comment: I don't know about OpenCV. If you want to process a frame from camera before Vuforia, it may not be possible. I think you have to use a different camera GameObject, separated from Vuforia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic workflow of Vuforia using Unity.

Start from [License Manager](https://developer.vuforia.com/license-manager)

- On the `License Manager` page go to `Add License Key`
- bPut in your details and if you don't plan to use a paid version in the `Select Plan` option click `None`

Now go to Target Manager

- First `Add a Database` (if you don't have one already) and give it a `Name`, add `License Key` and click `Create`
- Now inside your Database click `Add Target` and again put in all the details and upload your image.
- Now `Download Database` and make sure you've set it's usage to `Unity Editor`

Now within Unity

- Add your `ARCamera`
- Import the Database you downlaoded into Unity through `Assets` - `Import Package` - `Custom Package`
- Now in your Inspector Panel of ARCamera, you'll see `Data Set Load Behaviour` has your unity package name. Check it, and check `Active` as well
- Now in `Assets`, Go to `Qualcomm` - `Prefabs` - `ImageTarget` and drag Image Target onto the scene.
- In the `ImageTarget` `Inspector` you'll find `ImageTarget` behaviour and you can set the values to your Image.

From here on, what you do is completely up to you. You can add a Model or animate over is as you would on normal Unity applicatoins.

User Defined Targets can be found at: https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Unity-Load-DataSet-from-SD-Card

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks your help. But I know how I determine 2d marker and 3d target. But the vuforia use its marker detection algorithm. I want to use my own algorithm that find marker position. I am sorry because I didn't explain what I want to do.

Comment: OH! Are you talking about [User defined Targets](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Unity-Load-DataSet-from-SD-Card)?

Comment: Yes. I want to draw a rectangle on camera view. I crop this rectangle and save it as marker. I plan to load this image on runtime and track it.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the last line of the answer to say the same.  Please mark as answer if it's helped you :)